# simulation of transferring file

Tags: file-transfer, omnet++

I have simple question. In tic toe example two pc s exchange msg. I know that in omnet++ everything is message but how can I simulate transfer file. Is there some example on net with this. In real life file is segmented and send peace by peace (transport) layer. Question is do I need to simulate all this step (segmentation, creating packet, frame and so on..) I don t want to analyze TCP/IP stack just want simulation that transfer file like in real life (channel busy during segment transmission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you probably find an example or maybe even exactly what you need in the [INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org).

Modules in the **inet.applications.tcp** package, e.g. **TCPSessionApp** can be used to model file transfers. ([model components for the INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org/Protocols.html))